# What is wrong in this Spring Security configuration? How can I make an endpoint accessible to users having different authorities?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-rest

I am working on a Spring Boot protecting my APIs using Spring Security and JWT tokens and I have the following iusse.

I have an API handling endpoint like this: http://localhost:8019/api/admin/user/54/wallet

I have 2 user types:

- **ADMIN USER:** having **ADMIN** autority  defined into the JWT tokend.
- **CLIENT USER:** having **CLIENT** autority  defined into the JWT tokend.

The previous API must be accessible by both the user types (I know that the **/admin/** section in the URI is not the best...it will be refactored in the near future).

Then I have this class extending the Spring Boot **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter** class and implementing my security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    
    @Autowired
    private JwtConfig jwtConfig;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;
    
    
    private static final String[] USER_MATCHER = { "/api/user/email/**"};

    
    private static final String[] CLIENT_MATCHER = { 

                                                        "/api/users/email/*",
                                                        //"/api/admin/**",
                                                        "/api/admin/user/{userID}/wallet"
                                                    };
    
    private static final String[] ADMIN_MATCHER = { 
                                                        "/api/users/email/**",
                                                        "/api/admin/users",
                                                        "/api/admin/user/{userID}/wallet",
                                                        "/api/admin/**"
                                                        
                                                   };
    
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception 
    {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
    

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception 
    {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }   
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        /*
         * NOTE:
         * Using hasRole expects the authority names to start with 'ROLE_' prefix
         * Instead, we use hasAuthority as we can use the names as it is
         */
        http.csrf().disable()
                   .authorizeRequests()

                   .antMatchers(USER_MATCHER).hasAnyAuthority("USER")
                   .antMatchers(CLIENT_MATCHER).hasAnyAuthority("CLIENT")
                   .antMatchers(ADMIN_MATCHER).hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
                   //.antMatchers(CLIENT_MATCHER).hasAnyAuthority("CLIENT")
                   .antMatchers("/api/users/test").authenticated()
                   .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, jwtConfig.getUri()).permitAll()
                   .anyRequest().denyAll()
                   .and()
                   .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.addFilterBefore(
            new TokenVerificationFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtConfig, jwtTokenUtil),UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
    
    /* To allow Pre-flight [OPTIONS] request from browser */
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) 
    {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**",
                                    "/webjars/**",
                                    "/v2/**",
                                    "/swagger-resources/**",
                                    "/swagger-ui.html");
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder()
    {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    };


}
```

The problem is that as it is defined in the previous configuration if I try to call the previous API (http://localhost:8019/api/admin/user/54/wallet) with a token related to an user having the **CLIENT** autority I am obtaining this error message:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-02-13T20:22:10.418+00:00",
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden",
    "path": "/api/admin/user/54/wallet"
}
```

Viceversa if I try to call the previous API passing a token of an user having the **AMDIN** authority I obtain the expected API output.

It seems pretty strange to me because into the **CLIENT_MATCHER** I have defined this rule:

```
"/api/admin/user/{userID}/wallet"
```

The strangest thing is that if I remove this line from the **ADMIN_MATCHER**:

```
"/api/admin/user/{userID}/wallet",
```

that become something like:

```
private static final String[] ADMIN_MATCHER = { 
                                                    "/api/users/email/**",
                                                    "/api/admin/users",
                                                    //"/api/admin/user/{userID}/wallet",
                                                    "/api/admin/**"
                                                    }
```

Now the behavior is the complete opposite: using a JWT token of an user having the **CLIENT** authority I retrieve the expected output, but now using a JWT token of an user having the **ADMIN** authoruty I obtain this error message:

{
"timestamp": "2022-02-13T20:27:47.793+00:00",
"status": 403,
"error": "Forbidden",
"message": "Forbidden",
"path": "/api/admin/user/54/wallet"
}

and this seems pretty strange to me because the **ADMIN_MATCHER** contaisn this rule:

```
"/api/admin/**"
```

that should meaning: **access to all the API having an enptoint starting with "/api/admin/" folloed by anything else**.

What is wrong in my Spring configuration? What am I missing? How can I fix it in such a way that this API could be accessible using a JWT token having **ADMIN** or **CLIENT** authority?

Comment: The problem is the way you have written your rules. The rule that matches is the one that is used so if a request comes in and it finds `"/api/user/email/**"` it will find the first that matches, the one for USER. What you should write is `.antMatchers("/api/user/email/**").hasAnyAuthority("USER", "CLIENT", "ADMIN")` to allow all of them access. That is your security rule, it will not go over all rules it will detect the one that matches first (which also means that ordering is very important for your rules!).

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
.antMatchers(ADMIN_MATCHER).hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
```

try

```
.antMatchers(ADMIN_MATCHER).hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN", "CLIENT")
```

and removing this from CLIENT_MATCHER

```
"/api/admin/user/{userID}/wallet"
```

Comment: no...same problem

Comment: Why have I to remove "/api/admin/user/{userID}/wallet" from the CLIENT_MATCHER? This endpoint have to be enabled from CLIENT user

Comment: Usually you define the matcher with the endpoints - and specify which roles have access to the endpoint(s).  (instead of defining the access roles first, and then specifying what endpoints the role has access to) Also, the order of the matchers definition matter.

Comment: If you don't remove it from CLIENT_MATCHER, since CLIENT_MATCHER is checked before ADMIN_MATCHER, the CLIENT_MATCHER rule will be checked first, and it finds only CLIENT is allowed, so an admin user will be forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way you have written your rules. The rule that matches is the one that is used so if a request comes in and it finds `"/api/user/email/**"` it will find the first that matches, the one for USER.

What you should write is `.antMatchers("/api/user/email/**").hasAnyAuthority("USER", "CLIENT", "ADMIN")` to allow all of them access. That is your security rule, it will not go over all rules it will detect the one that matches first (which also means that ordering is very important for your rules!).

This applies to all your other rules as well BTW.